# Scons prints licensing error when compiling the code

Tags: python, c++, gcc, scons

I am getting the following error when I build a C++ source with Scons:

> license check failed

I have one C++ project and I have Python script to be used with Scons for building the project. When I run the `scons` command in the command prompt, the build starts and when the first source file is compiled, I am getting the following errors in the console:

> license check failed scons: ***
>   [C:\Engine\output\qnx700_screen_arm\core\stdafx.o] Error 1 scons:
>   building terminated because of errors.

After that, the compilation terminates. The thing is that I was able to build the project previously using Scons. These errors seem to start happening after I uninstalled Visual Studio but it might not be related. I am thinking of that because I see also the following warning:

> scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++
>   compilers most likely not set correctly

This is the code of the `SConstruct` file:

```
import os
engine_root = os.path.join("..","..","..")

# Hand over the execution to Engine/scripts/build.py
execfile(os.path.join(engine_root, "scripts", "build.py"))
```

Comment: What compiler are you expecting to be used? It seems what ever compiler you are trying to use requires a license, and assuming the file path mentioned has relevance, it looks like you are intending to use a QNX compiler, which is a licensed compiler. Are you sure your QNX compiler (usually comes with the Momentics IDE) has a valid license that hasn't recently expired?

Comment: Yes, I am using QNX Compiler. I have licenses for it. The thing is - if I execute the same compile command, that is generated by Scons in the command-prompt, the command is executed correctly and the object file is created.

Comment: Ok, in that case, probably the environment in which SCons is executing the command is different than the one in which you execute on the command line. SCons will create an environment from scratch, depending on what is in the SConstruct file, and ignore your shell environment. Did you run any scripts or have anything that would modify your shell environment to allow it use the compiler? I am thinking maybe there is a environment variable which points to a license file or something similar.

Comment: What @dmoody256 said. Likely you have an environment variable which provides info about the license. SCons doe NOT propagate your shell environment variables. (There's a FAQ on that one). So you either have to explicitly add it via env['ENV']['WHATEVER_LICENSE_VAR']='my license value', or copy it from the shell env['ENV']['WHATEVER_LICENSE_VAR']=os.environ['WHATEVER_LICENSE_VAR']

Comment: You very right, guys. It appears that some of the QNX environment variables were not set in the scons. After I set them in the script, it all works fine now. Thank you all. 

PS: If you can close this question, that would be great.